# Does inter mail server connection use mutual TLS (mTLS)?

Tags: email, encryption, smtp, mtls

I wondered how email is secured (encryption and signing), then googled this and got the following knowledge.

- Normally, end-to-end encryption is not performed. If it should be encrypted, another protocol such as S/MIME is needed.
- Inter mail server connection mostly be encrypted using StartTLS.

Though, I couldn't find out whether inter mail server connection uses mutual TLS or not.
In other words, when the sender's mail server (e.g., owned by Google) sends emails to the receiver's mail server (e.g., owned by Microsoft), the latter check the former's certificate and verify the sender is actually who he says he is?

Comment: Nope, no mutual SSL is used by default. It would be an interesting and effective security measure, but as well it would require all clients having their trusted client certificates.

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you for your comment.
If there are no mutual authentications in inter mail server connection as you said, emails totally can't be trusted.
For example, if an evil mail server pretends as a Gmail mail server, it can send any emails as Gmail users to any other mail servers and receivers including another mail server can't detect it.
I believe if the email is so vulnerable it couldn't pervade as now it does.

So that I believe there are any means pervaded which support mail servers' mutual authentications.

Am I wrong ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, email is much less secure than one would think and hope. Because I didn't understand email and had similar questions as you do, I spent several months researching all technical aspects of modern email, which resulted in [this article](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/).

As you have already figured out, [end-to-end encryption](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#end-to-end-security) is totally independent from everything else. Encrypting email in transit is optional, and the [percentage of TLS-secured connections](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#tls-deployment-statistics) increased from around 40% in 2013 to around 90% in 2020 as reported by Google/Gmail.

ESMTP itself provides only [opportunistic security](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#transport-security), which is useful only against passive attackers. As a result, the identity of the receiving server is often [not even verified](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#server-authentication).

There are two standards to provide confidentiality even in the presence of an active attacker, which aren't widely deployed yet:

- [DNS-Based Authentication of Named Entities (DANE)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#dns-based-authentication-of-named-entities)
- [Mail Transfer Agent Strict Transport Security (MTA-STS)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#mail-transfer-agent-strict-transport-security)

Authenticating that an email is coming from the sender's domain is [solved separately](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#domain-authentication) with the following standards:

- [Sender Policy Framework (SPF)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#sender-policy-framework)
- [DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#domainkeys-identified-mail)
- [Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance (DMARC)](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#domain-based-message-authentication-reporting-and-conformance)

These standards are more widely deployed than the previous ones, but we're still far away from "universal" adoption and enforcement. One of the reasons for this is that not everyone sees [email spoofing](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#spoofing) as a bug. [Mailing lists](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#mailing-list) use this as a feature.

Comment: Your article is fantastic! It helps me to understand how secured and not secured email is.

Comment: Thanks! (I hope I can fix that the browser scrolls to the right anchor when loading the page soon. In the meantime, you have to search for the above standards in the linked article.)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no mutual SSL is used by default

> emails totally can't be trusted

You are right. The same way as you cannot trust the name of the sender. However there are additional measures (not always used or enforced unfortunately) in the email header

- routing information (can be spoofed
- Domain Keys Identified Mail

see: https://blog.mailfence.com/email-header/

Comment: Relying on message header fields is dangerous because the sender can add any header field as well. Unless you know that your incoming mail server removes forged header fields (at least the ones you are interested in), you don't learn anything by inspecting them. See [my article](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#authentication-results-header-field) for more information.